# JsonArray with items not having id's

Tags: java, json, web, gson

Hi every one actually I want to make a com.google.gson.JsonArray of data:[1,2,3,4,5].How can i do that in java? any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5};
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(data);
```

Comment: No actuaually this will give me "data":"[1,2,3,4,5]" whereas I want "data":[1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: That's surprising. "data":"[1,2,3,4,5]" is not even valid JSON. Could you show your code?

Comment: Thanks Traroth , I got my problem fixed bu gson.toJsonTree(data).